# Fetching Key and value from Database as variable and value into a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, prepared-statement, resultset, jboss-4.0.x

I have a table with columns `ParamKey,ParamValue`. Now, I need to create the same set of key value pair in my servlet. That is, I need a variable of same name of key from the table and hold the paramValue from Table in it.

I have found many options for using hashmap and many other methods. But, I need this kind of structure.

Is there any way to do this?? Please suggest,

Comment: Do you need to put All the elements to the Hashmap, or just a few according to the key?

Comment: @GáborCsikós : I donot need a hash map. But, Need a variable whose name is the key which I get from DB and value of that variable will be the value from the table.